# Closing as off-topic: Any clue why we have some Portuguese words in this ?

Tags: discussion, bug

I decided to put a close vote on a question a few minutes ago and then I fell on some Portuguese words, a language I do love btw. Any clues ?

[image]

Comment: Não vejo Português. [Must be caching](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/).